# Optional tuples to Map in Scala

Tags: scala, dictionary, tuples, option-type, scala-collections

If I have a List of tuples, I can convert to a map with `toMap`:

```
val x = (3 -> 3)
List(x).toMap
```

and I get

```
scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(3 -> 3)
```

If I have a List of Optional and try the same I would get an error:

```
val x = Some(3 -> 3)
val y = None
List(x, y).toMap

<console>:15: error: Cannot prove that Some[(Int, Int)] <:< (T, U).
```

I want to get the same result. Is it possible?

Comment: What result exactly would you expect?

Comment: I would expect the same result as before, converting x and ignoring y because is a None:

scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(3 -> 3)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `flatten` on the `List` to remove the `None`s:

```
val x = Some(3 -> 3)
val y = None
List(x, y).flatten.toMap

> scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(3 -> 3)
```

Comment: note that there is an implicit conversion from `Option` to `List` in this case.